# Trailing solidus not allowed on element

Tags: php, xml, sabre

I am developing web application in php using soap api. I have the `xml format as shown below` to send the request to the api but I get the error like **Trailing solidus not allowed on element companyname** while viewing the xml in `postman`.

```
<OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" ResponseType="OTA" ResponseVersion="1.9.2" Version="1.9.2" AvailableFlightsOnly="true">
    <POS>
        <Source PseudoCityCode="PCC">
            <RequestorID ID="1" Type="1">
                <CompanyName Code="TN" />                            
            </RequestorID>                        
        </Source>                   

    </POS>
    <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="1">
        <DepartureDateTime>2016-03-15T11:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM"/>
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DEL"/>
        <TPA_Extensions>
            <SegmentType Code="O"/>                        
        </TPA_Extensions>

    </OriginDestinationInformation>
    <TravelPreferences ValidInterlineTicket="true">
        <CabinPref PreferLevel="Preferred" Cabin="Y" />
        <TPA_Extensions>
            <TripType Value="Return" />
            <LongConnectTime Min="780" Max="1200" Enable="true" />
            <ExcludeCallDirectCarriers Enabled="true" />                        
        </TPA_Extensions>

    </TravelPreferences>
    <TravelerInfoSummary>
        <SeatsRequested>3</SeatsRequested>
        <AirTravelerAvail>
            <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="2" />
            <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="CHD" Quantity="1" />                        
        </AirTravelerAvail>                    
    </TravelerInfoSummary>
    <TPA_Extensions>
        <IntelliSellTransaction>
            <RequestType Name="50ITINS" />                        
        </IntelliSellTransaction>                    
    </TPA_Extensions>                
</OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
```

I had googled the error but not found any solution. I also cannot determine what the error say so I need some help.

Screenshot: 
[image]

When I hover to the cross sign in line 5 I get the error like **Trailing solidus not allowed on element companyname** and when I hover to the line 6  I get error like **Unexpected end tag (requestorid) ignored.** Here I cannot determined what the error says. I think it's in the correct xml format.

Comment: Maybe you need something like `..<CompanyName .. > COMPANY_NAME_HERE </CompanyName>..`

Comment: Trailing solidus is that `/` you have in `<CompanyName Code="TN" />`. And since the next end tag is unexpected, I assume that you need to open and close `<CompanyName>`

Comment: When I open and closed the <CompanyName> tag then I get the error like `Unexpected end tag (source). Ignored. `

Answer (score 6):

I had this happen today, but all I needed to do was switch the response viewer type in Postman from "HTML" to "XML" and the errors went away. This probably happened since the server responding did not appropriately set the `Content-Type` header - it came in as `text/html` for me instead of `text/xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this has connection to self closing tag like `<CompanyName Code="TN" />`.

Just replace this with `<CompanyName Code="TN"></CompanyName>` and the error goes away.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
<POS>
 <Source PseudoCityCode="ThisShouldBeYourIPCCNotJustPCCasValue">
    <RequestorID ID="1" Type="1">
        <CompanyName Code="TN">TN</CompanyName>
    </RequestorID>
 </Source>
</POS>
```

Comment: Changing the content of the response is no option.